# SQL Databases Quota Website Hosting

Tags: upload, web-hosting

Id a 10gb Total SQL Databases Quota enough for a site that only has comments, not any pictures or videos? say each post was (in LONGTEXT, under mysql) about a paragraph - would this be enough for say a few million or hundread million posts? how may about? Really appreshate the help - I found a good host site "http://www.ixwebhosting.com/index.php/v2/pages.hostingPlans", but it only has the 10gb.

Comment: 10 gigabytes is almost certainly enough for *your* needs, and you can always upgrade if your web service becomes hugely popular. In fact, you'll almost certainly have to if that happens, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is no. The much more complicated answer is **not even close**. :)

You can get a rough sizing guess for database space by figuring out what cantent you want in your database, and multiplying that by the target number of users.

For instance, if you want users to be able to post an average webpage (say 4k), plus their user-profile, etc (perhaps another 1-2k) that would be 6K per user (in this very contrived example). if the users could upload additional content (forum posts, blog entries, friends lists, etc) this would be on top of it.

This doesnt include things like your own maintenance tables, other database storage requirements, etc.

This of course **assumes** that you aren't putting pictures, video, etc in the db which would bloat it even quicker.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on so many things. How many users do you think you will you have? What sort of content will they be allowed to upload? What quotas will you give your users?

But without knowing any of these, I'll just guess: no, 10 GB is not going to be enough for a site like Facebook. You would need terabytes of storage if your site became popular. The high resolution photos of people's cats alone would fill your 10G.